# How do I play audio though jackd from console?

Tags: linux, audio, jackd

```
OSS        | play
ALSA       | aplay
PulseAudio | paplay
JACK       | ?
```

What tool can I use to test if jackd is properly configured and make it play something?

Comment: I'm getting confused... But with [jackd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/jackd)  is it not enough that you use a couple of different application and you start to listen?

Comment: With PulseAudio you can also use different applications. But there is still simple minimal specific tool just to play/record from PulseAudio. I expect similar tool to be for JACK as well. If some application (especially if it can output to multiple sound modules) doesn't work it may be either JACK problem or the application problem. If the tool in question doesn't work, it is probably specifically JACK problem.

Comment: Do you mean something like [qjackctl](http://qjackctl.sourceforge.net/) and the sound from the microphone to the speakers?

Comment: No, it should be command-line. Just a minimal tool play WAV to JACK or record from JACK to WAV. There should be options to list ports, specify socket for connection to JACK, etc.

Comment: "jackd2" package in Ubuntu includes /usr/bin/jack_rec which records. I too am looking for a simple playback tool. VLC / mpv / mplayer would work, but those are a lot bigger packages then needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many Jack compatible media players, such as `mpv` (ffmpeg based) and `vlc`. See this [List of Applications](http://www.jackaudio.org/applications/)

Try `mpv --ao=jack test.wav`

As well, the `jackd2` package in Ubuntu 14.04 comes with a sample program called `jack_simple_client` which generates a test-tone output.

Comment: +1 for `jack_simple_client` which generates a test-tone when called with no arguments

Answer (score 0):

For a quick test you can do to simulate modem noise.

```bsh
cat /dev/urandom | aplay
```

[source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Configuring_Sound_on_Linux/HW_Address)

Comment: Cool trick - but that's alsa right? OP is asking for Jack

Comment: This made my blood curdle.

Comment: `aplay < /dev/urandom` for code golfers.